What does this symbol (that looks like a triangle on top of a thermometer) mean?
I can't find a single explanation online, and image search engines did not help either. One theory is that this refers to a pressure cooker, but I am not sure. My intention is to vacuum seal the glasses by boiling them, so I am a bit wary that the high temperature might damage them.


Regardless of what the symbol means, Weck glasses are intended for canning. They are absolutely suitable for water bath canning, without getting damaged. I have also used them for pressure canning, and also for that they work well, although I was somewhat unhappy with the performance of the rubber rings in that case. No glass breaking though.

I am reasonably sure but can’t yet find a source/citation for this, but it appears to refer to the “thermal shock” resistance. The symbol looks a lot like the delta used for “delta T”, or a change in temperature. That would fit with the symbol on the left which looks like the maximum temperature.
Taken together, it’s saying that it’s rated to a maximum temperature of 200°C and up to a 50°C temperature change, both which are typical of soda-lime glass.

That’s correct - and the reason why Weck states that for canning jars with cold contents go in a cool water bath and jars with hot contents in a warm or hot water bath. (And yes, I’d have to dig through my library to find that reference, if I even still have it.)

Interesting: Once I understand it it seems quite clear! I think it's the interpretation of the triangle as a delta which makes the difference. I first thought it might be a roof or something.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I noticed that the triangle is not the sane line thickness all the way around - it’s subtle, but that’s what convinced me to write an answer (plus when I looked up the thermal shock resistance and temp limit of soda-lime glass, it matched the numbers in the image).

This sounds about right, thanks a lot!

Weck's FAQ confirms this; "How do I avoid breakage? — In order to avoid thermal shock the temperature between the glass jar and the operating ambient temperature do not exceed max. 50 degrees C."

and so do their books and other sources. While not always giving specific temperatures they do give instructions to preheat glasses before filling with hot substances.

The Triangle is a "Delta" symbol, from the Greek character. It means "change". So yes.
